# SwitchCompat Thumb Size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appcompat

I would like to use the thumb that AppCompat provides, but with much larger size, so I can have a very large Switch

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:switchMinWidth="200dp"

      />
```

"app:switchMinWidth" allows me to have an extended width, but I can't increase the size of the thumb.